# Merge records from two tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two model `Part` and `DamagedPart`. 
All of them have `iid` field.

I want to get combined ActiveRecord object with data from these two tables.

Say, `parts` table has 10 records:

```
id: 1, iid: 100, d: 0
id: 2, iid: 150, d: 0
id: 3, iid: 200, d: 0
id: 4, iid: 240, d: 0
id: 5, iid: 433, d: 0
...
```

And `damaged_parts` table has only two records (for example):

```
id: 10, iid: 200, d: 4
id: 20, iid: 240, d: 7
```

Finally I need to get:

```
id: 1,  iid: 100, d: 0
id: 2,  iid: 150, d: 0
id: 10, iid: 200, d: 4 # <--- replaced from 'damaged_parts' table
id: 20, iid: 240, d: 7 # <--- replaced from 'damaged_parts' table
id: 5,  iid: 433, d: 0
...
```

Can I get this done by **one** AR query?

Rails: `4.2.7.1`
RDBMS: `MariaDB 10.0.27`

Answer (score 0):

You need `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE`

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.iid,
       COALESCE(dp.d, p.d) AS d
FROM   parts p
       LEFT JOIN damaged_parts dp
              ON p.id = dp.id
                 AND p.iid = dp.iid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select FROM parts WHERE iid LIKE'[1-]%';
UNION Select FROM damaged_parts  WHERE iid LIKE'[1-]%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
Part.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN damaged_parts ON parts.iid = damaged_parts.iid").select("coalesce(damaged_parts.id, parts.id) as id, parts.iid, coalesce(damaged_parts.d, parts.d) as d");
```